# When windows installer extracts files during installation

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation

My problems is slight different than the title,

I'm overriding the installer class method and I have written custom code which uninstalls the previous versions of application before installing the latest. So this uninstallation is part of the MSI.

So i'm expecting the MSI to first uninstall existing installation then start installing itself. I have this code within `OnBeforeInstall()` method.

```
  protected override void OnBeforeInstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
    {
        //Logic to uninstall pervious versions using product code
        base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
    }
```

But what I notice is even before coming to this uninstallation point installing MSI extracts all the files and overriting existing installation files. So where should i write my logic if i want to perform the uninstallation before executing MSI starts any of its operations ?